# SQL LEFT JOIN with COUNT(*) problem

Tags: sql, mysql, count, left-join, zero

I have the following query:

```
SELECT products_categories.categoryID, name, COUNT(*) AS itemCount
FROM products_categories
LEFT JOIN products_to_categories ON products_to_categories.categoryID = products_categories.categoryID
GROUP BY products_categories.categoryID
```

But still there's a problem: categories with no products in them return `itemCount = 1` instead of `0`. How can I fix this?

Comment: instead of LEFT JOIN just use JOIN

Comment: @YoK Thanks for the suggestion. Can you explain why JOIN would be better in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `COUNT(products_to_categories.categoryID) AS itemCount`? I am not really sure but would think that maybe the problem lies in the `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try `COUNT(product_name)` or whatever, instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
COUNT(products_to_categories.categoryID)
```

Asking for `COUNT(*)` gives you 1 at least because, after all, there *is* 1 row. Specific counts need specific treatment.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT products_categories.categoryID, name, COUNT(*) AS itemCount
FROM products_categories
LEFT JOIN products_to_categories ON products_to_categories.categoryID = products_categories.categoryID
GROUP BY products_categories.categoryID
WHERE itemCount <> '0'
```